# Historically, how did the total amount of salt / NaCl on Earth develop?

Tags: geology, geochemistry, earth-history, geochronology

After reading [this question about the origin of NaCl on Earth](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2956/what-is-the-origin-of-the-oceans-salt), I'm wondering: How did the amount of NaCl develop historically? Is it a more or less linear growth until today? Was it such a linear growth and then reached a level that it maintains until now? Or was that more complex over the billions of years of Earth's existence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a graph describing modern estimates of ocean salinity throughout the Phanerozoic (past ~550 million years). [image: Salinity from Hay et al., 2006]
The original PDF of this study can be found here:

[Hay, W.W., Migdisov, A., Balukhovsky, A.N., Wold, C.N., Flögel, S. and Söding, E., 2006. Evaporites and the salinity of the ocean during the Phanerozoic: Implications for climate, ocean circulation and life. Palaeogeography, Palaeoclimatology, Palaeoecology, 240(1-2), pp.3-46.](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/11894545.pdf)

As this graph shows, it is not linear at all and actually decreasing since the end of the Precambrian. This is a result of many factors including changing volume of ocean water, and the global chloride cycle. The details are all described in that paper.